# How to check which div page the user is currently viewing using jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check which div page is currently active on user's device, meaning which page is user currently viewing, and act accordingly. I have some divs and inside the divs I have some list entries and they are clickable, and if specific list entry is clicked different page is opened. And I want to be able to know in which div the user currently is, meaning I want to get the id of the div currently active on the user's device. Below you can find the sample html from my app.

**index.html:**

```
<div id="first" data-role="page">
...
   <li>
      <a href="#second" data-transition="slide">First</a>
   </li>
...
</div>

<div id="second" data-role="page">
...
   <li>
     <a href="#first" data-transition="slide">Second</a>
   </li>
...
</div>
```

This is just a small snippet. So I want to check whether user is currently in div with the id "first", or in div with the id "second". How can I check in which div page user currently is using jQuery or JS?

This doesn't seem to work for me:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('mobileinit', function() {
        $(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(event, ui) {
            alert("Current page is: ", $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('getActivePage')[0].id);
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it like this :

```
$(document).on('mobileinit', function(){
    $(document).on( "pagecontainershow", function(event, ui) {
        console.log($(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('getActivePage')[0].id);
    });
});
```

#### [Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/quduqotu/1/edit)

---

`jQuery.mobile.activePage`:

jQuery.mobile.activePage is **deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0** and **will be removed in 1.5.0**.

Use the **getActivePage()** method from the **pagecontainer widget** instead.

---

As you are using jQM 1.3+ then you can try this code:

```
$(document).on( "pagechange", function( event, ui ) {
   console.log($.mobile.activePage[0].id);
});
```

#### [Updated demo for jqM 1.3+](http://jsbin.com/quduqotu/2/edit)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me. I must use jquery mobile 1.3.1, and jquery 1.9.1.

Comment: @ett have you placed your script before jQuery mobile library.

Comment: yes I did that, but still no luck, you can see my edit above.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. I must use jquery mobile 1.3.1 and jquery 1.9.1

Comment: @ett wait i give a sample code which will work with your version of jqM.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try something like this: (untested)

```
$(document).bind('pagecontainershow', function(e, data) {

    if ($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == "first") {
        //do something..
            }
        }
        if ($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == "second") {
            //do some other thing..
        }

});
```